# Independent matches in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database with User, Content, and Topic nodes. I want to calculate the proportion of content consumed by a given user for a given topic.

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:CONSUMED]->(c:Content)<-[:CONTAINS]-(t:Topic)
WHERE ID(u) = 11158 AND ID(t) = 19853
MATCH (c1:Content)<-[:CONTAINS]-(z)
RETURN toFloat(COUNT(DISTINCT(c))) / toFloat(COUNT(DISTINCT(c1)))
```

Two things strike me as really ugly here:

- Firstly, is `COUNT(DISTINCT())` a hack to get round the fact that the two `MATCH` queries cross-join?
- Float division is ugly.

The second is something I can live with, but the first *seems* inefficient; is there a better way to express this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count of content should return the number of pieces of content a user consumed unless of course they consumed the same content more than once.

Instead of matching all of the content from the topic, if your model permits, you could just get the size of the outbound `CONTAINS` relationships.

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:CONSUMED]->(c:Content)<-[:CONTAINS]-(t:Topic)
WHERE ID(u) = 11158 AND ID(t) = 19853
RETURN toFloat(count(distinct c))/ size((t)-[:CONTAINS]->()) as proportion
```

Your original query returns a cartesian product of the number of user-content-topic matches x the number of topic-content matches. As an alternative to the above, you could re-write your original query something like this. This gets the content that is consumed by a user for the topic, does the aggregation and then passes the topic and resulting count to the next clause in the query. This will work, however, using `size((t)-[:CONTAINS]->())` will be more effiecient.

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:CONSUMED]->(c:Content)<-[:CONTAINS]-(t:Topic)
WHERE ID(u) = 11158 AND ID(t) = 19853
WITH t, count(distinct c ) as distinct_content
MATCH (t)-[:CONTAINS]->(c1:Content)
RETURN toFloat(distinct_content) / count(c1)
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's the detail I missed out - they can indeed have multiple CONSUMED links if they consumed it at different times. Sorry, will amend the post!

Comment: so do you want to count them distinctly then - correct? otherwise you could get into situations where they were over 100%.

Comment: Correct, yes - in easiest terms, I need a query to say "get me the proportion of this content that has ever been consumed"

Comment: Now you've introduced me to the `size()` function (yay, thank you!), I think this is slightly neater:

MATCH (u:User) WHERE ID(u) = 11158
MATCH (t:Topic) WHERE ID(z) = 19853
MATCH (u)-[:CONSUMED]->(c:Content)<-[:CONTAINS]-(t)
WITH COUNT(DISTINCT c) AS consumed,
     size((t)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Content)) AS total
RETURN toFloat(consumed) / toFloat(total) AS proportion

Is this as good as I'm going to get it?

Comment: i think that is as efficient as you get it. You always have to find all of the distinctly consumed content for a user and a topic. I updated the answer with some commentary and a rewrite your original query.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!